# Passing string from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I am using the PInvoke, reverse PInvoke scheme as described by Thottam R. Sriram http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/06/02/pinvoke-reverse-pinvoke-and-stdcall-cdecl.aspx

Everything seems to work well, except for passing a string from C++ to C.

( In Sriram the string is constructed in c# and passed untouched through c++, so the issue is avoided. )

The c# code looks like this

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void callback(string str);
    public static void callee(string str)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Managed: " + str);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        gpscom_start(new callback(Program.callee));

        Console.WriteLine("NMEA COM Monitor is running");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
    }

    [DllImport("gpscomdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void gpscom_start(callback call);

}
```

The C++ code looks like this

```
extern "C" dllapi void __stdcall gpscom_start(void (__stdcall *callback) (BSTR str))
{

BSTR bstr = SysAllocString(L"starting monitor");
(*callback)(bstr);
SysFreeString(bstr);
```

When run, everything looks good except the callback string

```
Managed: m
```

It looks like a UNICODE string being printed out by an ANSI routine, but surely c# strings are unicode?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When marshalling strings across a P/Invoke boundary, it is always good practice to use a `MarshalAs` attribute with the appropriate string type.  I think putting a `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]` on the parameter should take care of the problem.

```
public delegate void callback([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]string str);
```

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunsekhri/archive/2007/02/28/marshaling-bstrs-in-com-interop-or-p-invoke.aspx) has an similar example where someone was passing BSTRs between managed and unmanaged code, but he used `IntPtr` and some methods on the Marshal class. `Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR` seems most useful here.

Comment: Can you please expand on this?  My c# is not expert enough to know how to implement your answer.

Comment: @ravenspoint try changing the delegate to: `public delegate void callback([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string str);` importing the System.Runtime.InteropServices namespace if needed.  This tells the runtime that unmanaged code expects this to be a BSTR (or perhaps BSTR *, I am not an interop expert)

Answer (score 1):

C# strings are UTF-16. I would suggest that C# could be expecting an LPWSTR or something similar rather than a BSTR. If you look at the first example posted, he puts the call type as a wchar_t*, not a BSTR.

Comment: Yes, and so are BSTRs I believe.

Comment: BSTRs are not plain wchar_t*s, they are a different binary format. That's why SysAllocString exists.

Comment: Yes.  They are preceded by the string length.  As I understand it, BSTR(c++) == string(c#)