# Passing char * parameter to C# function

Tags: c#, c++, dll

C++ win32dll1.dll:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int getSerialNumber(char* outs)
{
    char s[2];
    s[0]='0';
    s[1]='1';

    for(int i=0; i < 2; ++i){
        outs[i] = s[i];
    }
    return 1;
}
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("win32dll1.dll")]
public unsafe static extern int getSerialNumber(char* ss);
```

Not able to pass `s` in the function

```
char[] s = new char[2];
getSerialNumber(s);
```

Shouldn't this work? Why or why not?

Comment: possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683013/interop-sending-string-from-c-sharp-to-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179270/pass-c-sharp-string-to-c-and-pass-c-result-string-char-whatever-to-c-s http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455234/passing-string-from-c-to-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use `StringBuilder` in the declaration:

```
[DllImport("win32dll1.dll")]
public unsafe static extern int getSerialNumber(StringBuilder s);
```

The CLR will automatically translate that to C++ `char*`, call the function, and then convert the result back and store it in the `StringBuider`.

Call it with something like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(2);
getSerialNumber(sb);
```

The number specifies the initial capacity in characters. In this example, it’s only 2 characters; if the C++ code writes more than that, your app will crash.

Comment: I don’ think OP *wants* a string. Looking at the example data provided in the question, I think `byte[]` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - They can just convert the `String` into a `byte[]` in that case.  Who knows what the author want their question was vague.

Comment: The example in the question clearly puts *characters* into an array in a method called *getSerialNumber*, which clearly means to retrieve a text string.